# Rails4 simple form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

undefined method `simple_form_for' for #<#Class:0x3d6c2a8:0x2d12f00>

```
<%= simple_form_for(@status, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
<% if @status.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
```

the first ruby code is the error line

Comment: do you have the simple form gem installed ?

Comment: yes i do, i did install it with boostrap, when i run bundle, it shows am using simple-form 3.0.1

Comment: without more context, it's really hard to provide an answer, so please give mote details about the context or give a link to your project (github, bitbucket, or anything else)

Answer (score 0):

Lose the round brackets.... and it should work
simple_form_for @status, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|